# UIWebView taps throws exception in iOS9

Tags: uiwebview, ios9

I'm developing a web application which has worked perfectly in previous versions of iOS but with the new release of iOS9 all taps that will load new urls throws an exception which I don't know how and where to handle:

```
*** WebKit discarded an uncaught exception in the
  webView:decidePolicyForNavigationAction:request:frame:decisionListener: delegate: 
  <NSInvalidArgumentException> *** 
setObjectForKey: object cannot be nil (key: BundleIdentifier)
```

Like I said, this doesn't occur on earlier versions.
Any ideas?

Comment: I have a similar issue running an app on iOS 9. When the user taps an input field in a UIWebView the app hard crashes and no error report is sent.